# Allowing for resets in an accumulating time series

Tags: time-series

I am extracting data from IP21 (a sensor historian logging system). This is a weightometer weighing material moving over a conveyer belt

I need to calculate hourly differences/increases from an accumulating figure

I can get these aggregated hourly measurements from my dataset:

- Minimum
- Maximum
- Average
- Standard Deviation
- Variance

Assuming the accumulating figure never resets, I can find the hourly change as

`Maximum-Minimum`

and this the incremental weight that has moved over the conveyer belt

However if the accumulating figure *does* reset in the middle of the hourly period, I will know only these things:

- Minimum = 0
- Maximum = last reading before reset
- Average
- Standard Deviation
- Variance

Can I work out the true incremental change from these figures?

If I had the last and first reading for the period (which I can actually get but it complicates things) then I could use this:

```
If Minimum = 0
   Added Weight = (Maximum - start period value) + end period value
else
   Added Weight = (Maximum - Minimum)
```

But I want to know if I can work it out from Min, Max, Avg, Std Dev, Var, or perhaps approximate it

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions on how I get a response on this? A NO with an explanation would suffice

Comment: Is the reset time random? Predictable?

Comment: Why does it complicate things to get the first and last reading for the period? Don't you have `start period value` available as the maximum for the previous period, and `end period value` available as the minimum from the next period?

Comment: With regards to reset time: from the dataset I have there has never been a reset, and I also don't know if there ever _will_ be one in future, I just need to allow for it in my integration logic so there is one less thing to go wrong.

Comment: With regards to minimum from next period: excellent idea. I didn't consider that. In short if I can derive the correct number on the current row then I have a simple solution, but the next best thing would be to use the minimum from the next period (row). I was mainly curious as to whether I could use the pre-calculated period statistics (Avg, Std Dev, Var) to approximate the true difference.

Comment: How much do you know about the increment pattern? Is it approximately linear, or does it have any other parametric form (quadratic/sinusoidal/whatever)?

Comment: It based on measuring material moving over a conveyer belt. The pattern would be a mostly linear change over a certain period (limited by the capacity of the equipment loading at one and and processing at the other), followed by periods where there is no material at all. So I guess it's a linear change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume the process is *completely* linear, with no stops, then you can write down a system of equations and solve it. Suppose the linear equation for the hour is $y = mx + b$ where $y$ is the readout, $x \in [0,1]$ is the fraction of the way through the hour, and $b$ is the readout at the beginning of the hour. Suppose it resets at time $t$. We now have three unknowns--$m$, $b$, and $t$--and three algebraically independent variables that are functions of these unknowns--maximum, average, and standard deviation. (Variance is the square of standard deviation so it's not independent of the other three.) Explicitly, your equations are:

$$\mathrm{maximum} = mt + b$$
$$\mathrm{average} = E(y) = \int_0^t mx + b\, dx + \int_t^1 mx\,dx$$
$$\mathrm{variance} = E(y^2) - E(y)^2 = \int_0^t (mx + b)^2\, dx + \int_t^1 (mx)^2\,dx - (\mathrm{average})^2$$

Hopefully you can solve these for $m,x,b$ relatively easily.

The wrinkle comes in when your trend is not completely linear, in which case this solution is only approximate. If you have an explicit model for how it deviates from linearity, you could try to solve that model, although it might get annoying. Another approach is to take your data (you said you had some sample data but it didn't include any resets), modify it by inserting *fake resets* at random points, and see how close the approximate solution above is to the true solution. If it's close enough, you can use it, and if it's not, then you should look for another solution, like using the numbers from the next period like I described above.

Comment: Excellent thanks for your response. Actually I can't solve those relatively easily but I appreciate you posting a response!